# Is it ok to cold smoke steak before freezing?

Tags: freezing, steak, storage, smoking

About to wrap up a 60 day dry aged ribeye. After slicing to 2" thick cut steaks and trimming the pellicle i was debating on cold smoking with cherry for two hours. I've done this before but directly grilled. Instead im looking to freeze this round but from my research I havent seen any direct issues.

So this leads me to ask are there any issues with cold smoking a ribeye before freezing or should I freeze and cold smoke the day I'm going to cook to temp? Steaks will be vaccum sealed and probably when ready to cook dropped into a sous vide for 6 hours. Doubt these will be frozen past 6 months

Answer (score 1):

No issues, **as long as you control the temperature and remain outside the danger zone**.  In other words, can you cold smoke below 40F (4.5C)?

Time in the danger zone is cumulative.  Freezing does not re-set the clock.  If you can't stay out of the danger zone during the smoke step, I would smoke, sous vide, then freeze.  This is probably a more common approach.  You can then re-therm the steak directly from frozen when you are ready to eat.

As an aside, 6 hours seems like a long time to sous vide a rib-eye...even from frozen.